# why do subscript operators C++ often comes in pair?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, constants, operator-keyword

[C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/multidim-arrays3.html) is defining a template container `Matrix` to avoid tricky `new` `delete` code. Tutorial says that subscript operators often come in pairs ? Why is it so ?

```
T&       operator() (unsigned i, unsigned j); 
T const& operator() (unsigned i, unsigned j) const;
```

Why is it so ?

This is also called : const-overloading.

FAQ gives clues. Do you have additional comments ?

In particular, should `mutate()` observe certain rules to be used safely on const objects only ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Operator overloading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading)

Comment: To be fair, it's mentioned there only for `operator[]` (array-like classes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call of subscript operator on a `T&` object, first non-const operator is called. Then, inspect and mutate operations are allowed.

Call of subscript operator on a `T const &` object, second const operator is called. Then, inspect is allowed, but mutate is not allowed.

Example is here

```
void f(MyFredList const& a)  ← the MyFredList is const
{
  // Okay to call methods that DON'T change the Fred at a[3]:
  Fred x = a[3];
  a[3].inspect();

  // Error (fortunately!) if you try to change the Fred at a[3]:
  Fred y;
  a[3] = y;       ← Fortunately(!) the compiler catches this error at compile-time
  a[3].mutate();  ← Fortunately(!) the compiler catches this error at compile-time
}
```

Credits to C++ FAQ, more [here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/const-overloading.html).

Answer (score 8):

To put it simply, because there are two sides to an assignment: the left side and the right side.

The non-const version: `T& operator() (unsigned i, unsigned j);` is intended primarily for the left side of an assignment (i.e., to be used as the target of the assignment).

The const version: `T const& operator() (unsigned i, unsigned j) const;` is intended exclusively for the right side of the assignment.

Note the difference in wording there though: the const version can *only* be used on the right side of the assignment, whereas the non-const version *can* be used on either side. If, however, you have a `const`-qualified object, you can only invoke const-qualified member functions, so in this case it can't be used at all. This is exactly what you (at least normally) want -- it prevents modifying an object you've said shouldn't be modified (by const-qualifying it).

As far as `mutate` goes, it's typically used only for objects that have some difference between their *logical* state and their *bit-wise* state. A common example is a class that does some (usually expensive) calculation lazily. To avoid re-computing the value, it saves the value once it's computed:

```
class numbers { 
    std::vector<double> values;
    mutable double expensive_value;
    bool valid;
public:
    numbers() : valid(false) {}

    double expensive_computation() const { 
        if (valid) return expensive_value;
        // compute expensive_value here, and set `valid` to true
    }
};
```

So here, the result from `expensive_computation` depends purely on the values in `values`. If you didn't care about speed, you could just re-compute the value every time the user invoked `expensive_computation`. Calling it repeatedly on a const object will always produce the same result though -- so having called it once, we'll assume it may be called again, and to avoid doing the same expensive computation repeatedly, we just save the value into `expensive_value`. Then, if the user asks for it again, we just return the value.

In other words, from a *logical* perspective, the object remains `const` even when/if we modify `expensive_value`. The visible state of the object doesn't change. All we've done is allow it to do the const things more quickly.

For this to work correctly, we'd also want to set `valid` back to false any time the user modifies the contents of `values`. For example:

```
void numbers::add_value(double new_val) {
   values.push_back(new_val);
   valid = false;
}
```

In some cases, we might also want an intermediate level of validity -- we might be able to re-compute `expensive_value` more quickly by (for example) knowing exactly which numbers have been added to `values`, rather than just having a Boolean to say whether it's currently valid or not.

I should probably add that C++11 adds some new requirements with respect to both `const` and `mutable`. To make a long story short, under most circumstances, you need to ensure that anything that's `const` and/or `mutable` is also thread-safe. You might want to watch [Herb Sutter's video](http://herbsutter.com/2013/01/01/video-you-dont-know-const-and-mutable/) on this. I do feel obliged to add, however, that I think his conclusion with respect to `mutable` is probably a *little* exaggerated (but I'd rather you watched and decided on your own than take my word for it).

Comment: Good thanks! "If, however, you have a const-qualified object, you can only invoke const-qualified member functions, so in this case it can't be used at all. ", you mean the non-const version cannot be used at all ?

Comment: "As far as `mutate`goes..." - you show a case where const can be called on a non-const member (using `mutable`), and illustrate with a lazy calculation example where the logically const-member can see its value change, is that right? I am asking because explanation for example is very clear and complete, but I missed why it comes there.