# Why is this object is not getting copied by value

Tags: c++

When I return the object temp in the operator* function, it is not getting copied to p3 in the main.

The cout statements inside the operator* function is returning correct values but p3 in main has only garbage.

Also I am getting a _block_type_is_valid(phead->nblockuse) at the return 0 statement of main.

Here is the code.

```
#pragma once
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Polynomial
{
private:
    int *coefficients;
    int length;
public:
    inline int getLength() const {return length;}
    Polynomial(int length);
    Polynomial(const Polynomial &p);
    Polynomial():coefficients(nullptr){}
    ~Polynomial(void);
    extern friend Polynomial operator*(const Polynomial &p1,const Polynomial &p2);
    inline int operator[](int n) const { return coefficients[n];}
    inline int& operator[](int n) { return coefficients[n];}
    Polynomial& operator=(Polynomial &p);
    friend void swap(Polynomial& first, Polynomial& second);
    void resize(int x);

    friend istream& operator>>(istream &is, Polynomial &p);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, Polynomial &p);
};
```

Here is polynomial.cpp

```
#include "Polynomial.h"

Polynomial::Polynomial(int length){
    this->length = length;
    coefficients = new int[length];
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        coefficients[i] = 0;
    }
}


Polynomial::~Polynomial(void){
    cout<<"Deleting: "<<coefficients;
    delete[] coefficients;
}
/*
Polynomial Polynomial::operator*(Polynomial p){
Polynomial temp(length + p.getLength());

for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
for(int j = 0; j < length; j++){
temp[i+j] += coefficients[i] * p[j];            
}
}   
cout<<temp;
return temp;
}*/

Polynomial operator*(const Polynomial &p1,const Polynomial &p2){
    Polynomial temp(p1.getLength() + p2.getLength());

    for(int i = 0; i < p1.getLength(); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < p2.getLength(); j++){
            temp[i+j] += p1[i] * p2[j];         
        }
    }   
    cout<<temp;
    return temp;
}
void Polynomial::resize(int x){
    delete[] coefficients;
    coefficients = new int[x];
}
void swap(Polynomial& first,Polynomial& second){
    int tempLength = first.getLength();
    int *temp = new int[tempLength];
    for(int i = 0; i < first.getLength(); i++)
        temp[i] = first[i];
    first.resize(second.getLength());
    for(int i = 0; i < first.getLength(); i++)
        first[i] = second[i];
    second.resize(tempLength);
    for(int i = 0; i < first.getLength(); i++)
        second[i] = temp[i];
    delete[]temp;
}
Polynomial& Polynomial::operator=(Polynomial &p){
    swap(*this,p);
    return *this;
}
Polynomial::Polynomial(const Polynomial &p){
    //if(coefficients) delete [] coefficients;
    coefficients = new int[p.getLength()];
    for(int i = 0; i < p.getLength(); i++)
        coefficients[i] = p[i];
}
istream& operator>>(istream &is,Polynomial &p){
    cout<<"Enter length: ";
    is>>p.length;
    p.coefficients = new int[p.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < p.length; i ++)
        is>>p.coefficients[i];  
    return is;
}
ostream& operator<<(ostream &os,Polynomial &p){ 
    for(int i = 0; i < p.length; i ++)
        if(p.coefficients[i])
            os<<p.coefficients[i]<<"x^"<<i<<" ";        
    return os;
}
```

Here is main

```
#include"Polynomial.h"

#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    Polynomial p1,p2,p3;
    cin>>p1>>p2;
    p3 = (p1 * p2);
    cout<<p3[0]<<p3[1]<<"here";
    cout<<p3;

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Here is the final corrected code. All I needed to do is initialize the pointers with null and length with 0 in all constructors.

```
#include "Polynomial.h"

Polynomial::Polynomial():
    coefficients(nullptr),length(0){}

Polynomial::Polynomial(int length):coefficients(nullptr),length(length){    
    coefficients = new int[length];
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        coefficients[i] = 0;
    }
}

Polynomial::~Polynomial(void){  
    if(coefficients) delete[]coefficients;
}

Polynomial& Polynomial::operator=(const Polynomial &p){ 
    if(coefficients)    
        delete[]coefficients;

    length = p.getLength();
    coefficients = new int[length]; 
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        coefficients[i] = p[i]; 

    return *this;
}
Polynomial::Polynomial(const Polynomial &p):
    coefficients(nullptr),length(0)
{   
    length = p.getLength();
    coefficients = new int[length]; 
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        coefficients[i] = p[i];     
}

Polynomial operator*(const Polynomial &p1,const Polynomial &p2){
    Polynomial temp(p1.getLength() + p2.getLength());
    for(int i = 0; i < p1.getLength(); i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < p2.getLength(); j++)
            temp[i+j] += p1[i] * p2[j];         
    return temp;
}

istream& operator>>(istream &is,Polynomial &p){
    cout<<"Enter length: ";
    is>>p.length;
    p.coefficients = new int[p.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < p.length; i ++)
        is>>p.coefficients[i];  
    return is;
}
ostream& operator<<(ostream &os,Polynomial &p){ 
    for(int i = 0; i < p.length; i ++)
        if(p.coefficients[i])
            os<<p.coefficients[i]<<"x^"<<i<<" ";        
    return os;
}
```

Comment: Not sure how this compiles as `operator=` takes a reference and `(p1 * p2)` returns a temporary that won't bind to a non-const reference.  Change both `operator*` and `operator=` to take const refs and try it. Also `operator*` should probably not be a member function.

Comment: When you return objects by value, like for your multiplication operator, a temporary object is created and then destructed. What do you think happen with the pointer in this temporary object? It's copied and then *deleted* when the temporary object is destructed. So what does the copy now point to? You need to obey the [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28writing%29).

Comment: You are talking about garbage values, but this code should not even *compile*. `error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'Polynomial'`

Comment: GCC won't compile this.

Comment: I am using visual studio. I cannot use const Polynomial& in either of these functions as visual studio says, "No operator matches these operands, operand types are const Polynomial [int]" where I use the p[i] commands.

Comment: Check out the "Law of Three" and then use a `std::vector<>`. Your object is not getting "copied by value" because the code that should implement it is broken. The initial suggestion should help you avoid even having to write that code.

Comment: @Souradeep: that's because you forgot to implement a `const` version of `operator[]`, so that you can use the function on const objects. e.g. a member with signature `const int& operator[](int n) const` or maybe `int operator[](int n) const` depending on whether you want people to have references to coefficients.

Comment: Fixed it. Now it is saying invalid allocation size.

Comment: @SouradeepNanda: The purpose of a question on SO is not that you gradually fix your originally posted code as you receive more answers and comments, until the problem finally disappears. What future use would such a question then be? You'd have to inspect the modification history to find out what was really going on...

Comment: @ChristianHackl Sorry I havent posted too many questions on Stack Overflow. I didnt know that.

Comment: @SouradeepNanda: Well, SO's intention is also to build kind of a knowledge database, like a dictionary or an encyclopedia. SO questions and answers often turn up on top of Google search results. That's great, because other programmers will surely have the same question as you in the future, and thus find an answer without even having to ask themselves. If you gradually remove the actual problem or question from your original text, then you effectively take away this benefit. It's often better to ask a new question based on the new insights you gained from the answers of an older question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code must not compile – if you invoke your compiler with the right flags. **There is no C++ compiler which works well with default flags!**

For example, let's take Visual C++ 2013, invoked like this, with a few non-default flags:

```
cl /nologo /EHsc /Za /W4 stackoverflow.cpp
```

The result is, correctly, a compiler error:

```
stackoverflow.cpp(78) : error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'Polynomial' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

        stackoverflow.cpp(19): could be 'void Polynomial::operator =(Polynomial &)'
        while trying to match the argument list '(Polynomial, Polynomial)'
```

Now let's see what happens if we remove the `/Za` flag, which disables Microsoft extensions:

```
cl /nologo /EHsc /W4 stackoverflow.cpp
```

The error goes away. However, a **warning** appears:

```
warning C4239: nonstandard extension used : 'argument' : conversion from 'Polynomial' to 'Polynomial &'
        A non-const reference may only be bound to an lvalue; assigment operator takes a reference to non-const
```

And finally, let's see what the compiler does if we remove `/W4`, the warning-level flag:

```
cl /nologo /EHsc stackoverflow.cpp
```

No errors, no warnings. That's *bad*. `p3 = (p1 * p2);` is not standard C++. Even though you can make Visual C++ compile the code, nothing good will come of it.

The right signature of the assignment operator would be:

```
Polynomial& Polynomial::operator=(Polynomial const& p);
```

The biggest problem with your code, however, is the use of `new[]` and `delete[]`. You certainly have a memory leak somewhere (construction and assignment both allocate, but only the destructor deletes), and even worse, you delete the same array multiple times.

Add the following output to your destructor:

```
Polynomial::~Polynomial(void){
    std::cout << "coefficients address destructor: " << coefficients << "\n";
    delete[] coefficients;
}
```

If you run it now, you will see something like:

```
Enter length: 2
100
200
Enter length: 3
100
200
300
10000x^0 40000x^1 40000x^2 coefficients address destructor: 00463BF8
coefficients address destructor: 00463BF8
1040000herecoefficients address destructor: 00463BF8
```

Three times `00463BF8`! This is undefined behaviour and can lead to every imaginable thing to happen in your program.

But how can this be?

The answer is that your `operator*` returns a shallow copy of a `Polynomial` object. The pointer inside is copied, and you end up with two pointers pointing to the same allocated memory.

You need a **copy constructor**. And you must respect the so-called Rule Of Three: if you need to implement *one* of copy constructor, copy assignment operator and destructor, then you need to implement *all* of them.

Nevertheless, instead of taking all the trouble and implement dynamic allocation with its countless pitfalls manually, do yourself a favour and use `std::vector` instead of a pointer and a length variable:

```
class Polynomial
{
private:
    std::vector<int> coefficients;
    // ...
};
```

Your subscript operator also needs modification. In fact, you'll need two of them, one for const access and one for non-const access:

```
inline int operator[] (int n) const { return coefficients[n];}
inline int& operator[] (int n) { return coefficients[n];}
```

See [why do subscript operators C++ often comes in pair?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15435738/why-do-subscript-operators-c-often-comes-in-pair)

Finally, I think you misunderstand `extern`. You don't need it to use `friend` functions. Just remove it from your code; otherwise GCC won't even compile it.

Here is a complete example with the most important fixes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Polynomial
{
private:
    std::vector<int> coefficients;
public:
    inline int getLength() const {return coefficients.size();}
    Polynomial(int length);
    Polynomial(){}
    Polynomial operator*(Polynomial &p);
    inline int operator[] (int n) const { return coefficients[n];}
    inline int& operator[] (int n) { return coefficients[n];}

    friend istream& operator>>(istream &is, Polynomial &p);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, Polynomial &p);
};

Polynomial::Polynomial(int length) :
    coefficients(length)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        coefficients[i] = 0;
    }
}

Polynomial Polynomial::operator*(Polynomial &p){
    Polynomial temp(coefficients.size() + p.getLength());

    for(int i = 0; i < coefficients.size(); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < coefficients.size(); j++){
            temp[i+j] += coefficients[i] * p[j];            
        }
    }   
    cout<<temp;
    return temp;
}

istream& operator>>(istream &is,Polynomial &p){
    cout<<"Enter length: ";
    int length;
    is>>length;
    p.coefficients.clear();
    p.coefficients.resize(length);
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i ++)
        is>>p.coefficients[i];  
    return is;
}
ostream& operator<<(ostream &os,Polynomial &p){ 
    for(int i = 0; i < p.coefficients.size(); i ++)
        if(p.coefficients[i])
            os<<p.coefficients[i]<<"x^"<<i<<" ";        
    return os;
}

int main(){
    Polynomial p1,p2,p3;
    cin>>p1>>p2;
    p3 = (p1 * p2);

    cout<<p3[0]<<p3[1]<<"here";
    cout<<p3;

    return 0;
}
```

You don't need a self-written copy constructor, copy assignment operator or destructor anymore, because `std::vector` knows how to copy, assign and destruct itself, in a safe manner without low-level memory problems.

Further examples for future improvement:

- Check that `std::cin` actually received valid integers.
- Implement `operator*` in terms of `operator*=`.
- Make `operator*` take a `const` reference.
- Don't use `using namespace` at global scope in header files.

Generally, read up on `const` and on best practices for operator overloading.

Comment: I know about vector. I am purposefully avoiding it for school reasons. Yes cin has received valid integers, it is just copying incorrectly.

Comment: @SouradeepNanda: Well, then make it copy correctly. Google for "copy swap idiom". Note that `new[]` and `delete[]` only superficially correspond to what `std::vector` does inside. The default allocator of `std::vector` uses placement new, but that's probably too advanced for beginners. And you generally need to check for valid user input. What would you think of a program that just *crashed* if you entered "xyz" instead of a number?

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming it compiles.*

You do not have a copy constructor, it is not a good idea. If you implement a destructor, you probably need assign-copy-swap-move functions. [What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) (and a half)

Also, it is better to use `std::vector` instead of dynamic allocation, since it automatically implements these behaviours, and the compiler generated constructors are enough then.

In your case returning creates a shallow copy (auto generated copy-cstr), but after the function returns, the original gets destroyed - which has allocated the memory the shallow copy is referencing - and freeing the memory.

It could be enough:

```
class Polynomial
{
private:
    std::vector<int> coefficients;

public:
    inline int getLength() const { return coefficients.size(); };
    Polynomial(int length): coefficients(length, 0) {};
    Polynomial operator*(const Polynomial& p); //you are not modifying p, thus const ref can work

    extern friend istream& operator>>(istream &is, Polynomial &p);
    extern friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, Polynomial &p);
};
```

Alternatively, you can use the array solution, and implement it right with all of the necessary stuff:

```
class Polynomial
    {
    public:
        Polynomial(int length);
        ~Polynomial();
        Polynomial(const Polynomial& other);
        friend void swap(Polynomial& first, Polynomial& second) // nothrow
        Polynomial& operator=(Polynomial other)
        {
            swap(*this, other);
            return *this;
        }

        int getLength();
        Polynomial operator*(const Polynomial& p); //you are not modifying p, thus const ref can work

        extern friend istream& operator>>(istream &is, Polynomial &p);
        extern friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const Polynomial &p);
    };
```

This is the [copy swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom).

Edit: you need a `inline int operator[](int n) const { return coefficients[n];}` too.

Comment: I created my own copy constructor, the problem still persists.

I know I can always use vectors but in school they still use naked pointers and dynamic arrays.

Comment: edited, add a const version too, also try to create with the signatures I defined.